# A word to express meanings highly developed AND naturally evolved

Tags: single-word-requests

My sentence is
**Human Brain** - [word] **Computer System**

**Human Brain** - **a** [word] **Computer System**         will work as well

Now the problem is when talking about technology we use the word '*develop*' and its derivatives. I'm comparing biological components with technology and I want a word to express a combination of meanings - 'light years ahead of current technology' and 'naturally evolved'.

Comment: You're not gonna get that in one word; you'll probably need something like "a highly developed biological computing system".

Comment: @Hellion Yeah, that's what i planned to do if I didn't get the word. thanks for phrase though

Comment: How are those sentences, even with *[word]* replaced by the word you seek?

Comment: @Drew It is actually my title, but titles too are sentences, no? :)

Comment: Well, if you ask an AI to fill in the blank, you may not like the answer:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***[supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer)*** is

> a computer with a high-level computational capacity compared to a general-purpose computer.

More broadly, it is a computer that is exceedingly better than other computers.

I think you can use this word in conjunction with *biological* to generate a good title that suits your needs. The title would be:

> ***(The) Human Brain - A Biological Supercomputer***

This suggests that the human brain is both more advanced than standard (technological) computers as well as biologically generated (or evolved).

Answer (score 0):

Consider "Human brain, a **transcendental** computer system".

> Definition: going beyond ordinary limits, idealistic; surpassing or
>   superior to the natural plane of reality or knowledge; being beyond
>   ordinary or common experience;

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/innate
>
> **innate** *adjective*
> 1.
> existing in one from birth; inborn; native
> 2.
> inherent in the essential character of something
> 3.
> originating in or arising from the intellect or the constitution of the mind...

**Innate** captures the *natural quality* requested, while **"Computer System"** already metaphorically implies that the *human brain is highly developed*.

- Human Brain - innate Computer System
- Human Brain - an innate Computer System
- Human Brain - the innate Computer System

Answer (score -1):

What about **"a n²th Generation Computer System"**?

I can also suggest "revolutionary"

**"Human Brain - A Revolutionary Computer System."**

> - constituting or bringing about a major or fundamental change. "A revolutionary new product" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionary)

- "innovative" and "pioneering" are synonyms and might also fit.

Comment: Since we don't know when we will be able to achieve working artificial system with same computing power as brain, I don't think its wise to include a fixed number. Also 3rd generation is out-dated instead of being futuristic, but thank you for fast reply, to @Hellion too :)

Comment: Maybe nth generation?

Comment: @Centaurus:  Shouldn't the superscript 2 be after the n?  I like nsquared-th...much more apt than merely nth when referring to a human brain...or even a cat's brain.

Comment: @ab2 I really don't know.  But if you say so, I can change it.

Comment: @Centaurus:  I think you have coined a new term.  I have never seen nsquared-th or nthsquared.  But I like it, especially in this context.  Some terminazi will undoubtedly object if it does not exist.

Comment: @ab2 yes I agree.

Comment: @Centaurus It is probably the best thing that I'm gonna get in short time.

Answer (score -3):

How about the word *cutting-edge*?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain why this phrase is a good answer.